# Loop jQuery and assign on each change?

Tags: javascript, html, color-picker

```
$(".control").on("change", function() {

      $(".img").each(function() {
        let src = $(this).attr(src).split("&width")[0] +
          '&width=' + $('#size2').val().replace('#', '') +
          '&height=100&RenderText=' + $('#name').val().replace('#', '') +
          '&TextSize=' + $('#size1').val().replace('#', '') +
          '&TextColor=%23' + $('#clr1').val().replace('#', '') +
          '&BgColor=%23' + $('#clr2').val().replace('#', '');
        $('#1Img').attr('src', src);
      });
    });


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
Font Size: <input class="control textsize" id="size1" onchange="update()" value="55" size="3"> Font Color: <input class="control jscolor" id="clr1" onchange="update()" name="color" value="FF0000" size="6"> Background Color: <input class="control jscolor"
  onchange="update()" name="color" id="clr2" value="FFFFFF" size="6"> Width: <input class="control textsize" id="size2" onchange="update()" value="355" size="4">
<input class="textsize" id="name" onchange="update()" value="[field title]" type="hidden">
<br/> Style 1: <img class="img" id="Img1" alt="Image 1" src="https://test.com/imgService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&postid=657406&width=350&height=100&RenderText=name+here&TextSize=55&TextColor=%23ff0000&BgColor=%23"> Style 2: <img class="img" id="Img2" alt="Image 2"
  src="https://test.com/imgService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&postid=655506&width=350&height=100&RenderText=2nd+style+name+here&TextSize=55&TextColor=%23ff0000&BgColor=%23">

<br/><br/>
```

Test loop  code here : http://jsfiddle.net/xu291Lqr/

Working code for single image : http://jsfiddle.net/3ugfzL68/4/

Hi, 
I have many images on my page, so i want to pass value to all images input by users. i have done it for single image  successfully, but stuck with loop . Can any one please help me in this. or is their any batter way to do this. 
Im new to javascript or coding to please consider my request as newbie. Sorry for poor English use in my question. hope you understand my points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

By reading the reference documentation above, you can see the definition is

```
jQuery.each( array, callback )
```

where `callback` takes the form `function( index, value ){}`

So you need to instead,

```
window.update = function(){
  $.each($("img"),function(i,v) {
    let $v = $(v);
    console.log('$v',$v,v); // note $v vs v
    let src = $v.attr("src").split("&width")[0]+
    '&width='                 + $('#size2').val().replace('#', '') + 
    '&height=100&RenderText=' + $('#name').val().replace('#', '') + 
    '&TextSize='              + $('#size1').val().replace('#', '') + 
    '&TextColor=%23'          + $('#clr1').val().replace('#', '') + 
    '&BgColor=%23'            + $('#clr2').val().replace('#', '');
    $v.attr('src', src); 
  });
}
```

Also note, that your `.img` should have been `img` --- `img` is a HTML element, whereas `.img` is a query selector for a class attribute. (e.g. `.img` would find `<img class="img">`, but not `<img>`. Just use `$('img')` instead)

Additionally, you have no `class="control"` anywhere, so the `.change` function would never be called.

The `$.each` needs to go inside a `$('input').on('change',function(){})`, but you need to remove all instances of `onChange='update()'` in those input elements if that's the route you want to go. You could also just put `$.each` inside of a `function window.update = function(){}`  --- Let me know if either of those two don't make sense or don't work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer , sorry im newbie so some time stuck even their is information about things, i update code here but its not change (update ) when we change input , can you please look into this http://jsfiddle.net/xu291Lqr/1/  .. very thank you for your time and help    ..

Comment: Check the last paragraph of my answer